# Search a string in files in the current directory, omit duplicates

Tags: bash, shell, files, grep, search

Assuming I want to write a line which prints out lines which match a specific string without repeating duplicate lines .. I want to search for this string in the files of the current directory:

`grep mystring ***What to put here?** | sort | uniq`

How can I search in all of the current dir files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -exec cat {} + |
  grep mystring |
  LC_ALL=C sort -u
```

Or:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -exec cat {} + | awk '
  /mystring/ && !seen[$0]++'
```

With GNU `grep`:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -hr --exclude-dir='?*' mystring | LC_ALL=C sort -u
```

Or with `zsh` and GNU `grep`:

```
grep -h mystring ./*(D.) | LC_ALL=C sort -u
```

---

To also search in files in sub-directories, recursively:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + |
  grep mystring |
  LC_ALL=C sort -u
```

Or:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | awk '
  /mystring/ && !seen[$0]++'
```

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -hr mystring | LC_ALL=C sort -u
```

Note that all those solutions also look inside hidden files (and files inside hidden directories), but not in non-regular files and wouldn't follow symlinks (unless you use some old version of GNU `grep` with `-r`).

Comment: Wat if I do this `grep mystring * | sort | uniq ` ? Doesn't this search in all the current dir files?

Comment: @SijaanHallak, that would also look inside non-regular files, that would not look inside hidden files. That would fail if some file names start with `-`. That could fail if you have a large number of non-hidden files in the current directory. If there's more than one file, that would include the file names in the output (GNU `grep` has a `-h` option to remove them).